# Partial HTTP Redirect

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5, virtual-directory

I have a website in IIS 7.5 with 3 virtual directories.

I want to create a redirect for only one of them.

For example:

http://www.mysite.com/ -> will redirect to http://www.mysite.com/site1/

but
http://www.mysite.com/site2/ -> will not redirect
http://www.mysite.com/site3/ -> will not redirect

How can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a default Page for `/site1` (such as `default.aspx`).

On that page load, redirect the site to wherever you want (can be done both in client and server sides).

Another options is to use a plugin like [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) plugin to redirect your HTTP request. The plugin is relatively easy to use and is compatible with IIS (I know for a fact that it's compatible with IIS v6.0).